# How do I display the value of count() inside blade view in Laravel 5.4?

Tags: php, laravel-5.4

I feel like I will be kicking myself for asking this question but I just can't seem to figure it out. What I'm trying to do is count the value of a collection right inside a blade view and display the result at the same time. Here's the simple code I have written

Controller

```
$pendingMembers = Member::where('status', '=', null)->get();
```

I can see the data when I die and dump $pendingMembers.

Blade view

```
<div class="mr-5">

{{ $pendingMembers->count() }} Pending

</div>
```

And that returns `Undefined variable: pendingMembers` so how can I achieve my desired goal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Share your variable in your controller method to your view file.

```
return view('your-blade-file', compact('pendingMembers'));
```

More details are available on https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/views#passing-data-to-views.

Comment: I knew I was going to kick myself for this. Thanks I didn't do that initially.